# Jquery methods (click,change) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, cakephp

I am in process to upgrade the code of cakephp 2.6 application to cakephp 3.7 
the jquery code written in the view files under the application not working anymore which was working earlier.

Below is the code sample which is not working

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#CouponAllowTime").click(function () {           
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#timeDiv").show();
        } else {
            $("#timeDiv").hide();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I tried to run code using $(document).on(), it works

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $(document).on('click','#CouponAllowTime',function () {            
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#timeDiv").show();
        } else {
            $("#timeDiv").hide();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to change several files of the application for this change, what is an issue here?

Comment: when any dynamic html you write after page load, then you need to use `$(document).on()` instead of  `$("#CouponAllowTime").click()`

Comment: I know, but I am not writing any html after page load. HTML element for "#CouponAllowTime" id is load initially with the page. Same code is working on live site I am doing change in my local host

Comment: may be new version of cakephp implementing html dynamically so.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I am also assuming same, this will increase my workload to change each and every related code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While upgrading from one version to another version, controls are generated dynamically. To attach event on dynamically created element you have to use ***delegated event handlers*** that is implemented using [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to give the container name : 

$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#CouponAllowTime","#your button container name").click(function () {    
       console.log("clicked !")       
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#timeDiv").show();
        } else {
            $("#timeDiv").hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first example binds the event handler directly to the element. The event will still bubble (unless you prevent that in the handler) but since the handler is bound to the target, you won't see the effects of this process.

The second example demonstrates the event delegation. The event handler is bound to an element higher up the DOM tree (in this case, the document) and will be executed when an event reaches that element having originated on an element matching the selector.

This is possible because most DOM events bubble up the tree from the point of origin. If you click on the #id element, a click event is generated that will bubble up through all of the ancestor elements (side note: there is actually a phase before this, called the 'capture phase', when the event comes down the tree to the target). You can capture the event on any of those ancestors.

By delegating an event handler, you can ensure it is executed for elements that did not exist in the DOM at the time of binding. If your #id element was created after your second example, your handler would never execute. By binding to an element that you know is definitely in the DOM at the time of execution, you ensure that your handler will actually be attached to something and can be executed as appropriate later on.